# How to create Libgdx jar file using Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, libgdx

I already created a jar file but whenever I click on it nothing happens, it doesn't open. so what I did is go to project structure -> artifacts -> jar -> from module to dependencies -> then select desktop module and DesktopLauncher as main class then save, then build artifact. The jar file doesn't even open, is there a way to create a jar file differently?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Terminal in IntellijIDEA (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or view->Tool Window->Terminal)

Run command

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```

Find your jar in desktop module -> build->libs->desktop-1.0.jar

When you double click on this and jar is not executed(run) then run with command prompt with command

```
java -jar desktop-1.0.jar
```

Comment: One may need to run `./gradlew desktop:dist` (in Linux) if gradlew is not in PATH.